# Problema en heroku con una app echa en Node.js

Tags: nodejs, express, heroku, deployment

Gente, desplegué mi app realizada en Node.js en la plataforma de Heroku pero se me crashea, incluso si reinicio Heroku al tiempo se me vuelve a crashear. Esta de mas decir que en local funciona correctamente la app. El error que tira Heroku es el siguiente

> 2020-10-05T17:16:42.680759+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10
> desc="App crashed" method=OPTIONS path="/api/auth"
> host=thawing-reaches-57928.herokuapp.com
> request_id=40695f32-c551-4490-89cf-5ce3b01677c7 fwd="131.100.100.91"
> dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

El servidor en express esta de la siguiente forma:

```
const express = require("express");
const conectarDB = require("./config/db");
const cors = require("cors");

// Crear el servidor
const app = express();

// Conectar a la BD
conectarDB();

// Habilitar cors
app.use(cors());

// Habilitar express.json para poder leer datos
app.use(express.json({ extended: true }));

// Puerto de la app
const port =  process.env.PORT || 4000;

// Rutas
app.use("/api/usuarios", require("./routes/usuarios"));
app.use("/api/auth", require("./routes/auth"));
app.use("/api/proyectos", require("./routes/proyectos"));
app.use("/api/tareas", require("./routes/tareas"));

// Iniciar el servidor  
app.listen(port, "0.0.0.0", () => {
    console.log(`El servidor esta funcionado en el puerto ${port}`)
});
```

**Codigo de ./routes/auth:**

```
const express = require("express"); 
const router = express.Router(); 
const { check } = require("express-validator"); 
const authController = require("../controllers/authController"); 
const auth = require("../middleware/auth"); 

// Iniciar Sesion 
// api/auth 
router.post("/", authController.autenticarUsuario ); 

// Obtener usuario autenticado 
router.get("/", auth, authController.usuarioAutenticado ); 

module.exports = router;
```

Alguna idea que puede ser? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: El archivo donde tenes este código se llama "index.js"? Podrías mostrar código de routes/auth?

Comment: @NicolasCavilla Si!

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const { check } = require("express-validator");
const authController = require("../controllers/authController");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");

// Iniciar Sesion
// api/auth
router.post("/",
    authController.autenticarUsuario
);

// Obtener usuario autenticado
router.get("/",
    auth,
    authController.usuarioAutenticado
);

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0):

Me sucedía lo mismo, pero buscando encontre la solución, es una bobería. Solo asegurate de que en *package.json* tengas el script de *start*:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
},
```

Answer (score -1):

Es por el puerto, tenes que usar el puerto (process.env.PORT || 3000) porque en primer lugar usarias el que te brinda heroku y en caso de que este no exista se usa el 3000

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).